# Is there a way to dynamically hide annotations that intersect map extent border?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, cartography, annotation

I have a feature linked annotation feature class with a number of annotations displayed only partially on the edges of the visible extent of the layout data frame.

The link annotation class will be used in a number of other maps of the same scale and paper size but showing different locations.

**Is there a way to dynamically hide the partially displayed annotations?**

*Out of the box solution preferred, programmatic (ArcObject, VB.Net Addin) acceptable*
[image]

Comment: +1 Great question. This capability should be built in to any decent labeling engine and available either by default or as an option. (It's not hard for a developer to code, nor would it lead to inefficient display: they just have to elect to exclude any text whose bounding box is not wholly contained in the map view.) If it's not already a part of ArcGIS, consider submitting an enhancement request.

Answer (score 1):

I do this with a bounding box. I had a script (that need to be update since it was in VBA), that create an extent rectangle in the map (as a .shp) and then I used it to select any annotations that intersects the boundary of my extent layers. Then I set the placement properties to those labels to "unplaced".

Could all be placed into a tool in ArcToolbox.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That would work with annotation feature class but this Question is about dynamic label placement.

Comment: Feature linked annotations are still in a geodatabase, right? Then it should work since the annotation are "physical" and not only dynamic (?)

Comment: True. I will see if I can come up with a script.